# ADB2C Custom policy for sending email through sendgrid

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, sendgrid-api-v3, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Other than optional steps, I have followed all steps mentioned below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid

I keep getting the following error when clicking through the "Send Veirification code" button -

*Basic credentials specified for 'SendOtp' are invalid. Check that the credentials are correct and that access has been granted by the resource.*

The sendgrid account is configured correctly and I am able to send email through Postman. The postman request, using the same sendgrid api key I am setting in Azure policy key

```
{
  "personalizations": [
    {
      "to": [
        {
          "email": "abc@abc.com",
          "name": "abc abc"
        }
      ],
      "dynamic_template_data": {
        "otp": "123456",
        "subject": "account email verification code",
      },
    }
  ],
  "from": {
    "email": "noreply@johndoe.com",
    "name": "John Doe"
  },
  "reply_to": {
    "email": "noreply@johndoe.com",
    "name": "John Doe"
  },
  "template_id": "d-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

These are the blocks from the above link that I have added

```
      <!--Step 1 SendGrid Email-->
       <ClaimType Id="Otp">
      <DisplayName>Secondary One-time password</DisplayName>
      <DataType>string</DataType>
    </ClaimType>
    <ClaimType Id="emailRequestBody">
      <DisplayName>SendGrid request body</DisplayName>
      <DataType>string</DataType>
    </ClaimType>
    <ClaimType Id="VerificationCode">
      <DisplayName>Secondary Verification Code</DisplayName>
      <DataType>string</DataType>
      <UserHelpText>Enter your email verification code</UserHelpText>
      <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
    </ClaimType>
    <!--Step 1-->
    <!--Step 2 SendGrid Email To be worked on -->
    <ClaimsTransformation Id="GenerateEmailRequestBody" TransformationMethod="GenerateJson">
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.to.0.email" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otp" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.otp" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.email" />
      </InputClaims>
      <InputParameters>
        <!-- Update the template_id value with the ID of your SendGrid template. -->
        <InputParameter Id="template_id" DataType="string" Value="d-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
        <InputParameter Id="from.email" DataType="string" Value="my_email@mydomain.com"/>
        <!-- Update with a subject line appropriate for your organization. -->
        <InputParameter Id="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.subject" DataType="string" Value="account email verification code"/>
      </InputParameters>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailRequestBody" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim"/>
      </OutputClaims>
    </ClaimsTransformation>
    <!--Step 2-->
      <!--Step 3 SendGrid Email-->
         <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountsignup">
      <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.0</DataUri>
    </ContentDefinition>
    <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountpasswordreset">
      <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.0</DataUri>
    </ContentDefinition>
          <!--Step 3-->
    <!--Step 4 SendGrid Email-->
    <DisplayControls>
    <DisplayControl Id="emailVerificationControl" UserInterfaceControlType="VerificationControl">
          <DisplayClaims>
        <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
        <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" ControlClaimType="VerificationCode" Required="true" />
      </DisplayClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <Actions>
        <Action Id="SendCode">
          <ValidationClaimsExchange>
            <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="GenerateOtp" />
            <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SendOtp" />
          </ValidationClaimsExchange>
        </Action>
        <Action Id="VerifyCode">
          <ValidationClaimsExchange>
            <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="VerifyOtp" />
          </ValidationClaimsExchange>
        </Action>
      </Actions>
    </DisplayControl>
    </DisplayControls>
    <!--Step 4-->
     <!--Step 5 SendGrid Email-->
      <ClaimsProvider>
    <DisplayName>One time password technical profiles</DisplayName>
    <TechnicalProfiles>
      <TechnicalProfile Id="GenerateOtp">
        <DisplayName>Generate one time password</DisplayName>
        <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.OneTimePasswordProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="Operation">GenerateCode</Item>
          <Item Key="CodeExpirationInSeconds">1200</Item>
          <Item Key="CodeLength">6</Item>
          <Item Key="CharacterSet">0-9</Item>
          <Item Key="ReuseSameCode">true</Item>
          <Item Key="NumRetryAttempts">5</Item>
        </Metadata>
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="identifier" />
        </InputClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otp" PartnerClaimType="otpGenerated" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </TechnicalProfile>

      <TechnicalProfile Id="VerifyOtp">
        <DisplayName>Verify one time password</DisplayName>
        <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.OneTimePasswordProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="Operation">VerifyCode</Item>
        </Metadata>
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="identifier" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" PartnerClaimType="otpToVerify" />
        </InputClaims>
      </TechnicalProfile>
     </TechnicalProfiles>
  </ClaimsProvider>
  <!--Step 5-->
  <!--Step 6 SendGrid Email-->
  <ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>RestfulProvider</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="SendOtp">
      <DisplayName>Use SendGrid's email API to send the code the the user</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send</Item>
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Bearer</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimUsedForRequestPayload">emailRequestBody</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="BearerAuthenticationToken" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SendGridSecret" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GenerateEmailRequestBody" />
      </InputClaimsTransformations>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailRequestBody" />
      </InputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
  <!--Step 6-->
  <!--Step 7 SendGrid Email-->
  <ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
      <Metadata>
        <!--OTP validation error messages-->
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfSessionDoesNotExist">You have exceeded the maximum time allowed.</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfMaxRetryAttempted">You have exceeded the number of retries allowed.</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfInvalidCode">You have entered the wrong code.</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfSessionConflict">Cannot verify the code, please try again later.</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <DisplayClaims>
        <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationControl" />
        <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" Required="true" />
        <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" Required="true" />
        <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" Required="true" />
        <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
        <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
      </DisplayClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress">
      <Metadata>
        <!--OTP validation error messages-->
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfSessionDoesNotExist">You have exceeded the maximum time allowed.</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfMaxRetryAttempted">You have exceeded the number of retries allowed.</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfInvalidCode">You have entered the wrong code.</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfSessionConflict">Cannot verify the code, please try again later.</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <DisplayClaims>
        <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationControl" />
      </DisplayClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
  <!--Step 7-->
```

Can any one help me figure how to debug this problem. Many thanks.

Comment: Are you using Basic Authentication at SendGrid or Bearer/API Key?https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/authentication/. Try to test your request in POSTMan or curl using the SendGrid link above with the credential you have obtained.

Comment: @Jas The Sendgrid account is an API Key account. According to the sendgrid documentation link you provided I have created an API key to be used as a Bearer/API Key and setting it in the CustomPolicy - which defines the Crypographic key in sendOtp as a BearerAuthenticationToken, so I am assuming the policy would send it as a Bearer token in the header. When I send that credential as bearer token from Postman it works and I receive email defined in the sendgrid template.

Comment: Everything looks ok so you may want to generate a new key at sendgrid and recreate it at B2C.

Comment: Jas, New Key doesnt work either. Tried putting an incorrect value to see if it triggers a diff response - doesnt. Also changed the StorageReferenceId to B2C_1A_SendGridApiKey as shown in the example https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/custom-email-verifcation-displaycontrol/policy/SendGrid/DisplayControl_TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml#L245 , as opposed to B2C_1A_SendGridSecret mentioned in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid - no difference. Deleting key from Policy keys in B2C triggers a diff message, so policy does read key

Comment: Have you tried specifying "UseClaimAsBearerToken" in the metadata? I'm guessing there needs to be a claim to carry the bearer token...

Comment: How dis u name the key? I mean did u provided the B2C_1A_ prefix or just let to set this by Azure? I had issues using this prefix earlier and fixed by adding this value manually at the creation.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace "my_email@mydomain.com" in the block with SendGrid account>Single Sender Verification> verified "DOMAIN"

[Like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTZuE.png)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. To fix it you have to do the following steps:

1. **Add a Sender:** To do so, navigate **Sender Authentication** page, and click **Create New Sender**. Next, you have to fill in all of the fields on the page and then click **Save**.

[image]

2. **Verify the sender:** You will receive a verification email that you need to confirm.
3. **Update the Custom policy's from.email parameter**

```
    <ClaimsTransformations> 
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="GenerateEmailRequestBody" TransformationMethod="GenerateJson">
        ...
          <InputParameter Id="from.email" DataType="string" Value="XXX@gmail.com"/>
        ...
      </ClaimsTransformation>
    </ClaimsTransformations>
```

4. **Update the Custom policy's template_id parameter**: If you are using a dynamic template you must update the template ID.

[image]

```
    <ClaimsTransformations> 
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="GenerateEmailRequestBody" TransformationMethod="GenerateJson">
        ...
        <InputParameter Id="template_id" DataType="string" Value="d-ac01c68f69364014adc44c7857f95d2e"/>
        ...
      </ClaimsTransformation>
    </ClaimsTransformations>
```

Comment: this was the actual issue and documentation of microsoft and sendgrid didn't include any such thing about verifying the send. Thanks